# Dynamically sized html video with elements directly below

Tags: html, css, video, position, size

I am making an html webpage with a video in the background and would like to accomplish the following using CSS:

- The video keeps its aspect ratio
- The video fills the width of the screen
- At relatively large window size the whole video is visible
- The video has a minimum height (i.e. when the window is shrunk, at a certain size, the whole video is no longer visible).
- There are elements positioned directly below the video, dynamically following it if the window is resized

It would also be nice if when the video is invisible it is centered (not crucial).

I've been trying this for ages now and have been able to get most of the points but not all of them; in particular I find the last point (positioning another element directly below) to be hard to combine with the others. I've been using the html `video` element and CSS.

Is this possible?

Comment: it's possible, where is the code that you have tried? hit Ctrl + M and add your code in the popup code editor

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Jquery plugin for this. I recommend looking at this one in particular.

[Vide - Jquery Plugin For Fullscreen Background Videos](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/)